# How to run the html file created in Sublime Text in Chrome directly?

Tags: html, google-chrome, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I tried creating a build system in sublime text and saving as chrome:

```
{
  "cmd":["C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe","$file"]
}
```

But it had no success.
On running with `ctrl B` it shows `No Build System`

Note: I have selected Chrome in build system.

What I can do solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of a `sublime-build` file has to be valid JSON in order for Sublime to recognize it, but the build that you posted above is not valid.

The `\` character is special in JSON (as in many programming languages as well) in that it indicates that the next character should be interpreted specially, for example `\n` meaning "start a new line".

In order to use a `\` character in a string, you need to double it to tell the JSON parser that it's just supposed to be a regular character and not special. For example:

```json
{
  "cmd":["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe","$file"]
}
```

Alternatively Windows generally accepts `/` in place of `\` in paths, which depending on your preference can be a little easier to look at visually:

```json
{
  "cmd":["C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe","$file"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just forgot basic thing.